# Publish SBT project with sub-projects as a single Maven artifact

Tags: scala, jar, sbt

I have an SBT project for a Scala library. The implementation is spread across multiple SBT sub-projects but I would like to publish the library as a single JAR. I've constructed the following example:

```
val subProject = project

val myLibrary = project
  .in(file("."))
  .dependsOn(subProject)
```

The project `myLibrary` it the main project which depends on all other sub-projects. If I run `sbt myLibrary/package`, I get a JAR files with just the class files, sources and rendered documentation of the sources in project `myLibrary`. I found the following workaround to include the files from the other sub-projects, by adding settings like the following to `myLibrary`:

```
val myLibrary = project
  .in(file("."))
  .dependsOn(subProject)
  .settings(
    Compile / packageBin / mappings ++= (subProject / Compile / packageBin / mappings).value,
    Compile / packageSrc / mappings ++= (subProject / Compile / packageSrc / mappings).value,
    Compile / packageDoc / mappings ++= (subProject / Compile / packageDoc / mappings).value)
```

What is the intended way to produce the same result?

Comment: Apparently, given nobody answered with a better solution, yours is the best. But it has a problem with `packageDoc` which complains because of the repeated "index.html` key in the mappings. At least with sbt 1.4.4.

Did you found any solution for that?

Comment: To avoid the duplicate key error, the line

`Compile / packageDoc / mappings ++= (subProject / Compile / packageDoc / mappings).value)`

should be replaced by

`Compile / doc / sources ++= (subProject / Compile / doc / sources).value`

I guess.

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin which creates fat jar (includes all the dependencies) of your project.

Comment: The readme of _sbt-assembly_ specifically discourages using the plugin to create an artifact for publishing. It also does not mention how it can be used to publish a source or JavaDoc JAR and whether the published `pom.xml` still mentions the aggregated set of dependencies of all sbt subprojects. I don't think _sbt-assembly_ makes my life easier in this regard. But Thanks anyway!

Comment: `sbt-assembly` creates a fat jar that includes all of the project's **dependencies**. The OP tries to publish **sub-projects** of a project into a single jar. Very different use cases, and as the OP mentioned this plugin does not help.